# When should ViewModel call Service methods?

Tags: oop, mvvm, architecture, soa, user-experience

For example, there is a `ViewModel` that has

- a collection of objects requested from a Service
- an `Add` command to create and add new objects
- a `Delete` command to delete selected objects

The User creates, adds and deletes objects by using corresponding commands.

How should ViewModel react on User's actions?

1. Should `ViewModel` immediately make a corresponding Service method call when the User invokes a command?

OR

2. Should `ViewModel` add / remove items from local collection, mark items as added / deleted and wait to make a Service method call only when the User invokes some `Save` / `Apply changes` button?

The second variant seems more complicated.

Does it give any performance / user experience benefit or enable any features that are not possible with the first variant?

In other words, is it better to keep `ViewModel` state as close to the Service / Database state as possible?

Comment: There are a few patterns that you can follow for this scenario, I would recommend the **[Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)**.

Comment: @MikeEason In terms of the article about Repository Pattern, my question is whether using a kind of _Web Service Repository against a Service behind_ to cache Service data and changes (similar to standard _Repository against a Database_) gives performance / user experience benefits or not.